# Ractive.js, access to parent property by named properties

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache, ractivejs

I have a *data* object:

```
var data = {
    examples: [
    {
        type: 'a',
        message: 'a'
    },
    {
        type: 'b',
        message: 'b'
    },
    {
        type: 'c',
        message: 'c'
    }
    ],
    filter: {
        a: true,
        b: false,
        c: true
    }
};
```

I'd like to show only those items from *examples* where *examples.type* is set to *true* in a *filter* object.

To illustrate the problem let me write pseudo-code for template:

```
<ol>
    {{#each examples}}
        {{#if ../filter[type]}}
            <li>{{message}}</li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

I need to get access to parent object properties, which I can do by *../* and get data from *filter* object using named properties.

How do I do that? I use RactiveJS.

Answer (score 4):

Your pseudo-code is 99% correct. The only issue is that inside an `{{#each ... }}` block you need to go up **two** levels of `../../filter`.

One to go from the individual array item to the array:

```
root/examples/0 --> root/examples
```

And one to go from the array to the data root:

```
root/examples --> root
```

Now the context is correct to find filter:

```
root/filter
```

However, since `filter` is already at the ractive instance data root, you can just use the `~/filter` syntax to directly access:

```
<ol>
    {{#each examples}}
        {{#if ~/filter[type]}}
            <li>{{message}}</li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

```js
new Ractive({
  el: document.body,
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    examples: [
    {
        type: 'a',
        message: 'a'
    },
    {
        type: 'b',
        message: 'b'
    },
    {
        type: 'c',
        message: 'c'
    }
    ],
    filter: {
        a: true,
        b: false,
        c: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive.min.js'></script>
<script id='template' type='text/html'>
<ol>
    {{#each examples}}
        {{#if ~/filter[type]}}
            <li>{{message}}</li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</ol>
</script>
```

Comment: I've just solved the problem in similar way and wanted to share the solution. Refreshed this page and saw your great explanation. In my case I used just `{{#if filter[type]}}` and seems it works. However, `../../filter` is more better readable, at least for me.